# Java error when creating an empty canvas within my Canvas() constructor

Tags: java, canvas

I am attempting to create a simple canvas using the Canvas class within Java AWT. These are the errors that I am getting: Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at Canvas$1.(Canvas.java:10) at Canvas.(Canvas.java:10)
Here is my code:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 public class Canvas extends JFrame {
   // constructor
    Canvas()
      {
    super("NewCanvas");

    // create a empty canvas
    Canvas c = new Canvas() {

        // paint the canvas
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            // set color to red
            g.setColor(Color.red);

            // set Font
            g.setFont(new Font("Bold", 1, 20));

            // draw a string
            g.drawString("This is a canvas", 100, 100);
        }
    };

    // set background
    c.setBackground(Color.black);

    add(c);
    setSize(400, 300);
    show();
}

// Main Method
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
}
```

}

I got this snippet from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-awt-canvas-class/
I am unsure why my constructor isn't initializing correctly.

Comment: That's not the error, that's part of the stacktrace. Please post the complete stacktrace

Comment: You're creating a new canvas within the constructor of the canvas? Won't that infinitely loop? Or dare I say it, cause a *stack overflow*? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) Maybe you're just missing a brace, but that's what it looks like.

Comment: What is a stack overflow? Relatively new to this stuff.

Comment: Why it's this very website you're on sir! Haha jokes aside, it's just the general term for running out of memory. The way I see it, it looks like your constructor is creating a new canvas, which will then call the constructor, which will create a new canvas, and on and on and on until you run out of memory and the program crashes.

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Your abbreviated stack trace you posted shows you have a stack overflow error. You are creating a new canvas object inside your constructor which will cause an infinite loop and thus a stack overflow.

You probably just want to remove that line as I don't see any reason why you would want a canvas to create another instance of itself when it's created.

```
Canvas()
      {
    super("NewCanvas");

    // create a empty canvas
    Canvas c = new Canvas() { //<------This is the problem line
```